# Using VLC to play/pause an audio track inside of separate functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, vlc, libvlc

I have one function (cmd_sr) that plays an audio track using the VLC-python lib.

I'm aiming to have different functions to pause, stop, change tracks, etc. But if I try to pause the track in a different function there's no change. It works fine if I add the p.pause() into the cmd_sr function.

Is there a way to embed the cmd_pause() function inside of the cmd_sr(), or somehow allow it to be accessed or paused by any function?

```
def cmd_sr(stream_url):
    global p
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer(stream_url)
    p.play()
def cmd_pause():
    print(stream_url)
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer(stream_url)
    sendMessage(s, "Tried to pause")
    p.pause()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't need to re-create the `MediaPlayer` once it is created.

One way to do that could be:

```py
# The player
p = None


def cmd_init(stream_url):
    global p
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer(stream_url)


def cmd_sr(stream_url):
    p.play()


def cmd_pause():
    sendMessage(s, "Tried to pause")
    p.pause()
```

But, using a global variable (here: *p*) is not very elegant. The best practice is to use a class:

```py
class MyPlayer(object):
    def __init__(self, stream_url):
        self.player = vlc.MediaPlayer(stream_url)

    def play(self):
        self.player.play()

    def pause(self):
        sendMessage(s, "Tried to pause")
        self.player.pause()
```